# How to calculate weighted sums of rows based on value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I searched around a lot trying to find an answer for this. It seems like what would be a relatively simple and common question, and I'm surprised I didn't find an answer but perhaps I am just not searching for the correct keywords.

I would like to calculate a weighted sum of some columns in three rows based on a value in another column. I think it makes more sense if you look at the dummy table below.

```
INDIVIDUAL <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B")

BEHAVIOR <- c("Smell", "Dig", "Eat", "Smell", "Dig", "Eat","Smell", "Dig", "Eat","Smell", "Dig", "Eat")

FOOD <- c("a", "a", "a","b","b","b", "a", "a", "a","b","b","b")

TIME <- c(2,4,7,6,1,2,9,0,4,3,7,6)

sample <- data.frame(Individual=INDIVIDUAL, Behavior=BEHAVIOR, Food=FOOD, Time=TIME)
```

Each individual spends a certain amount of time Smelling, Digging, and Eating each food item. I would like to weight and sum these three times to have one overall time per food item. Smelling is the lowest weight, eating is the highest. So basically I want a time interacting with each food item: Time per FoodA = (EatA) + (0.5*DigA) + (0.33*SmellA).

After extensive web browsing the best idea I could come up with was this:

```
sample %>%
  group_by(Individual, Food) %>%
  mutate(TIME = ((fullsum$BEHAVIOR == "EAT")
        +(.5*(fullsum$BEHAVIOR == "DIG")
        +(.33*(fullsum$BEHAVIOR == "SMELL")))))
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : incompatible size (2195), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1.

Any advice or direction to where this question has been answered already would be greatly appreciated!

**FINAL RESULT**

I modified fexjoo's suggestion to account for missing values and the result matches up with the values I calculated manually in Excel, so it looks like this is the winner. There may be a tidier way to remove the NAs from each of the columns but I'm ok with this.

```
data.frame %>%
  spread(BEHAVIOR, TIME) %>%
  mutate(EAT = coalesce(EAT, 0)) %>%
  mutate(DIG = coalesce(DIG, 0)) %>%
  mutate(SMELL = coalesce(SMELL, 0)) %>%
  mutate(TIME = EAT + .5*DIG + .33*SMELL)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how you get to calculate the weights. Are they arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
library(tidyr)

sample %>%
  spread(Behavior, Time) %>%
  mutate(TIME = Eat + .5*Dig + .33*Smell)
```

The result is:

```
  Individual Food Dig Eat Smell  TIME
1          A    a   4   7     2  9.66
2          A    b   1   2     6  4.48
3          B    a   0   4     9  6.97
4          B    b   7   6     3 10.49
```

Comment: `spread` is from `tidyr` package (also in `tidyverse`) just FYI

Comment: Thanks for your completion @Dan! I am working with `tidyverse` most of the time. Makes me forget the different packages sometimes :)

Comment: This worked but since I had some missing values (i.e. not every individual ate, smelled, dug every item) I had to replace the NAs with 0s within my piping. Thanks for the input!!

Comment: @KatieSmith Am I right that my answer solved your problem (except the fact that there were NA-values that you didn't mention in your post)? Would be great if you mark my answer as the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sample %>% 
group_by(Individual, Food) %>%
mutate(TIME = ((Behavior == "Eat") + (.5*(Behavior == "Dig")
                       +(.33*(Behavior == "Smell")))))
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I did try that previously, and I thought it wasn't working at all because the first couple dozen TIME values were 0. But I just did it again as you suggested and scrolled further down and all of the time values are 0 or 0.33, or 0.5, or 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
sample %>% 
mutate(weights=case_when(.$Behavior=="Smell"~0.33,.$Behavior=="Dig"~0.5,.$Behavior=="Eat"~1)) 
    %>% group_by(Food,Individual) 
    %>% summarise(WeightedTime=sum(weights*Time))
```

Which gives:

```
     Food Individual WeightedTime
  <fctr>     <fctr>        <dbl>
1      a          A         9.66
2      a          B         6.97
3      b          A         4.48
4      b          B        10.49
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error: Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : unknown variable to group by : INDIVIDUAL. Could be an issue with my data set but since one of the other options worked I am not going to troubleshoot it. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column with the weights based on the `Behavior` column:

```
library(dplyr)    
sample$weights <- 
    case_when(
        sample$Behavior == "Smell" ~ 0.33,
        sample$Behavior == "Dig" ~ 0.5,
        sample$Behavior == "Eat" ~ 1
    )

sample %>% group_by(Individual, Food) %>% 
    summarise(time = sum(Time * weights))
```

Comment: When I ran this I got an error during first part: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "WEIGHTS", value = c(0.33, 0.5, 1,  : replacement has 12 rows, data has 2194. Could be an issue with my data set but since one of the other options worked I am not going to troubleshoot it. Thanks for the suggestion though!